# Scala's state of type inference regarding Scalaz

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz

As seen in Alexej's answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010512/scalaz-validation-and-list-monad), when running sequence on a `Seq[Validation[X, A]]` you need a boilerplaty explicit type parameters `sequence[({type L[Y] = Validation[X, Y]})#L, Y]`.

The same need may happen with other datatypes / functions.

The questions related to eliminating the need for such explicit types via improving type inference are:

- Is it theoretically possible to do in Scala?
- If yes, is this on the Scala roadmap? When can the solution be expected?
- If not on the roadmap, then is the solution easy / moderate / hard to achieve?
- Can a mere human do anything to advance the case?

Any pointers regarding the issue welcome.

([Here is a slightly related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234095/why-is-scalas-type-inference-not-as-powerful-as-haskells), but not discussing the future perspective)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retronym says here [What are type lambdas in Scala and what are their benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits) that a future version of scala could improve this. So I guess that it is possible to improve the syntax. But, as far as I understand, we are facing some impossibility in Scala due to subtyping

Comment: If I understand correctly, Retronym references that future Scala could improve on the type lambda syntax, not on actually eliminating its need.

Comment: You can't eliminate it. How could you express a binary type constructor as an unary type constructor without it ?

Comment: That being said, it could be less uglier

Comment: @YoEight I mean eliminating the need for it in the actual case (via inferring the types). The type lambda construct can stay in general of course.

Comment: That would be great but I don't think it's possible because you could express type L[Y] = Validation[X, Y] or type L[X] = Validation[X, Y]. How the compiler can choose between those possibilities?